# Implement the description method of NSObject in c++ classes

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, nsobject

I'm debugging in Xcode an iOS application that contains C++ static libraries.
I'm able to see all my C++ variables but sometimes the information is partial or not fully answering my needs.
Is it possible to somehow implement the `"description"` method of `NSObjet` in my c++ classes so that when I right-click the c++ variable in my debugging window and choose `"Print description of variable-name"` the debugger will print my own description to the console?

Comment: if that code has debugging symbols for your source yes, otherwise no. Best of luck is to watch the assembly code and try to match the registers to what you have (hard to do that with opt-3 code).

Comment: The c++ code is fullY mine (that is I can change it as I want) and it has all debugging symbols and no optimizaions (O0).